# CocoaLumberjack Not Logging

Tags: cocoa, cocoalumberjack

I'm trying to integrate [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) into an existing project (so that I can get better logging on a customer's machine who is reporting a bug I can't duplicate). I've successfully built a sample project and got it to work in that, but it seems to do nothing in my own app.

I've copied the Lumberjack directory to my project directory and added that to the project. I've added the following to my 'Prefix.pch' file:

```
#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDASLLogger.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"
#import "DDFileLogger.h"

static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
```

I've placed the following in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

```
[DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
```

Finally I have the following in `-awakeFromNib`

```
NSLog(@"%@", @(ddLogLevel));
NSLog(@"%@", @(LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE));
NSLog(@"%@", @"About to DDLog");
DDLogError(@"This is an error.");
DDLogWarn(@"This is a warning.");
DDLogInfo(@"This is just a message.");
DDLogVerbose(@"This is a verbose message.");
NSLog(@"%@", @"Done with DDLog");
```

The console shows:

```
2014-05-26 14:57:13.530 [21943:303] 31
2014-05-26 14:57:13.530 [21943:303] 31
2014-05-26 14:57:13.530 [21943:303] About to DDLog
2014-05-26 14:57:13.531 [21943:303] Done with DDLog
```

I've tried stepping through the library's source code, but it's honestly above my head. Any assistance in figuring out what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, I got onto other ways to solve the problem and then to other projects. Perhaps I'll come back to it when I have time.